# Bundle 120 MB of audio files in Ionic 2 App

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am developing an Ionic2 app where, nearly 130 MB of audio files need to be used in the app. What should be the best approach to tackle the issue ?

The client wants to keep the initial app size small.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your audio files are in uncompressed audio format like .wav then you can use [this plugin](https://github.com/keenan/cordova-phonegap-audio-encode) to encode them (or any other software like [audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) if they are just static files).

If your audio files are already compressed like mp3, mp4, m4a etc then unfortunately there is nothing you can do other than being more clever in what you bundle in your app (if at all possible). So maybe bundle up only the essentials and donwload the rest via a CDN after installation.

Essentially it's the same as making a zip archive of jpg images. There will be minimal to almost no data size gained.